# Java - for loop - input Scanner - String

Tags: java, for-loop, double, java.util.scanner

I have a small question.
I want to add some double data.

-- TRIANGLE --

```
        System.out.println("field A");
        a = sc.nextDouble();
        sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("field B");
        b = sc.nextDouble();
        sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("field C");
        c = sc.nextDouble();
        sc.nextLine();

        System.out.println("height H");
        d = sc.nextDouble();
        sc.nextLine();
```

Is any option to input this double data in a for loop?

4 double data,

First loop - add a field,

Second loop - add b field,

...

Comment: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_for_loop.htm

Comment: you could use a for loop and store a, b, c, d in an array.  Then, you can do a = array[0], b = array[1], and so on.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of declaring multiple variables, you can populate the data into a `Map`, e.g.:

```
Map<String, Double> data = new HashMap<>();
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
for(String key : new String[]{"a", "b", "c", "d"}){
    System.out.println("Enter : " + key);
    data.put(key, scanner.nextDouble());
}
```

Once done, you can access the values using `data.get("a");`

Comment: Side note: you can also use the "new" lamda syntax: `Arrays.asList("A", "B", "C", "Height").forEach((key) -> { /* ... */ });`. But it does not provide a huge gain in this example.